# Gulp + CJSX: Unexpected indentation while parsing

Tags: compiler-errors, coffeescript, gulp, reactjs

Okay so I'm trying to use React+Coffeescript and I'm using Gulp to compile it. I'm not too familiar with gulp, but I know that it's having trouble dealing with the cjsx. (It stops the error if I remove my `render:` method)

Gulpfile:

```js
gulp.task('js', function () {
    return browserify({
        entries: [ SRC + 'scripts/index.cjsx' ],
        extensions: ['.cjsx', '.coffee'],
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.min.js'))
    //.pipe(streamify(uglify({ mangle: false })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(DIST + 'js'))
    .pipe(notify({message: 'JS Complete.'}))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

File throwing the parsing error:

```cjsx
React = require 'react'
Header = require 'components/Header.cjsx'
Footer = require 'components/Footer.cjsx'
Store = require 'Store'
Actions = require 'Actions'

Home = React.createClass

  displayName: 'Home'

  getInitialState: ->
    Store.toJSON()

  componentDidMount: ->
    Store.listenTo Store, 'change:counter', this._onChange

  componentWillUnmount: ->
    Store.stopListening Store, 'change:counter', this._onChange

  _onChange: ->
    @setState Store.toJSON()

  render: ->
    return
      <div>
        <Header />
        <h1> HI from React and CJSX </h1>
        <Footer />
      </div>

module.exports = Home
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the gulpfile? Is there some other node_module that I need? I know there isn't a whitespace issue, I've checked for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be the newline after your `return` statement. The compiler sees that as an empty return, the end of the `render` method, then encounters further indented code it doesn't know what to do with.

Try the following:

```
render: ->
  <div>
    <Header />
    <h1> HI from React and CJSX </h1>
    <Footer />
  </div>
```

Or, if all else fails, putting everything on one line.

Comment: you sir are a gentleman and a scholar! How were you able to check that? I typically use js2.coffee, but the JSX messes it up

Comment: I just eyeballed it, really. The nature of coffeescript, being both dynamic and whitespace-sensitive, is such that visual inspection tends to be quicker than drilling into errors. That, and your note about the render method was a dead giveaway.

Answer (score 0):

Your file seems to be ok according to this page:
https://jsdf.github.io/coffee-react-transform/

Maybe you need to talk a little bit more about your environment (gulp) or post the error.